# The infinite slide from right to left

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using the below code for the slider from right to left infinite loop but it's not working.

I have found so many solutions but they have been added multiple times Same HTML. I don't want that.

```css
.slider-container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .slider {
    display: flex;
    animation: slideRightToLeft 03s linear infinite;
  }
  
  .slider-card {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 200px; 
    height: 150px; 
    background-color: #f0f0f0; 
    margin-right: 20px; 
  }
  
@keyframes slideRightToLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-30%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-card">Card 1</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 2</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 3</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 4</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 5</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 6</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 7</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 8</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 9</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 10</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 12</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 13</div>
    
    <!-- Add more cards as needed -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want continuous with CSS only then you do need two copies of the items. So, are you saying you want a JS solution? What have you tried?

Comment: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-a-css-only-infinite-scroll-animation

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I have checked the above link, You have added manually an image animation delay. I have dynamic code.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Also you have a showing. a single image in a single frame and I have to show all the images on the screen. so I have removed grid CSS from the body

Comment: @AHaworth, Just solution can also work

Comment: I invite you to read the whole article and not stop at the first demo ... I am giving a generic code that works with any kind of content and as many frame as you want.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Yes I have tried, You have added nth-child for images but in my condition, it's different, I am getting data dynamicall

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found the solution using jQuery.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    animateSlider();
  });

  function animateSlider() {
    $('.slider').animate({
      marginLeft: '-=220px' // Adjust value according to the width of the cards and margin
    }, 1000, 'linear', function() {
      $(this).css('marginLeft', '0').find('.slider-card:last').after($(this).find('.slider-card:first'));
      animateSlider(); // Call the function recursively for infinite loop
    });
  }
```

```css
 .slider-container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .slider {
    display: flex;
    animation-duration: 01s;
  }
  
  .slider-card {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 200px; /* Adjust card width as needed */
    height: 150px; /* Adjust card height as needed */
    background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Adjust background color as needed */
    margin-right: 20px; /* Adjust margin between cards as needed */
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-card">Card 1</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 2</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 3</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 4</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 5</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 6</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 7</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 8</div>
    <div class="slider-card">Card 9</div>
    <!-- Add more cards as needed -->
  </div>
</div>
```